# How to eject external harddrive, if it's already offline?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, eject

I had issues ejecting 2 external harddrives. I got the usual

> Problem Ejecting USB Mass Storage Device
>
> This device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that
> might be using the device and then try again.
>
> OK

There's this trick everywhere on the internet that you can go to diskmgmt.msc and mark the drive offline, which safely ends any read/write. Which is what I did, but the 2 disks are still under the "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" menu, and I still get the above message when I try to eject any of the 2 drives I have.

Now I can't even use tools like Process Explorer to find which process is using the drive, because I don't have a disk letter anymore.

Any solutions to figure out what uses my **Offline** harddrives?

Answer (score 1):

The Event Viewer can be very useful in this kind of situations. There is no need to use external tools like Process Explorer.

Check the Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc), and under Windows Logs --> System, you should see some warnings with Kernel-PnP as soource. For me it was:

> The application
> \Device\HarddiskVolume2\ext\OpenHardwareMonitor\OpenHardwareMonitor.exe
> with process id 5440 stopped the removal or ejection for the device
> USB\VID_1058&PID_107C\574343344534464844333934.

All left to do is to safely exit that application and then safely eject that drive.